# checkbox event fired from another checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I'm wasting time trying to fire a binded action from another checkbox (with jQuery)

http://jsfiddle.net/gasparirob/ZbMHQ/

as you can see, if I click the first checbox, the alert is fired (when the checkbox is checked). But if I click the second checkbox (that checks the first checkbox too), the alert doesn't fire!

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to invoke it manually

```
$('#checkThis').change(function(){
    $("#target").prop("checked", $(this).is(':checked'))
                .change();
});

$('#target').change(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        alert ('checked');
    }
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZbMHQ/1/

I've also changed your code to use `.prop()` which makes it more clear.

Comment: 4 hours spent... and you solved it in 2 minutes... :-)
Even if I don't have fully undertand why the .attr (or the .prop) wasn't enough...

Comment: @Roberto Gaspari: it was enough, but I removed unnecessary `if` from your code

Answer (score 0):

Because you check only if your checkbox with id "target" is checked and after you make an laert add this and your second checkbox works like the one:

```
$('#checkThis').change(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        alert ('checked');
    }
});​
```

Comment: The question is why the even't isn't triggered.

Comment: could you explain better? :-)))
(in italian, also, if you want ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

You can manually fire the change event on the first checkbox in that case:

```
$('#checkThis').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $("#target")
            .attr("checked","checked")
            .change();
    } else {
        $("#target")
            .attr("checked",false)
            .change();
    }
});
```

[Fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZbMHQ/4/)

Comment: like the first answer: why the .attr() was not enough?